# CDF of $Y$ given the CDF of $X$ and $Y=X^2$

Tags: probability, cumulative-distribution-functions

> Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with CDF $F_X$, and $Y=X^2$. Find the CDF of $Y$.

My solution:
$$F_Y(t)=P(Y \leq t) = P(X^2 \leq t) =  
P( -\sqrt{t} \leq X \leq \sqrt{t}) =  $$
$$P(X \leq \sqrt{t}) - P(X \leq -\sqrt{t}) = F_X(\sqrt{t}) - F_X(-\sqrt{t})$$ (assuming $t \geq 0$, otherwise $F_Y(t)=0$).

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Are you clear as to where continuity of $X$ is used?

Comment: @geetha290krm That's great. There's not much to choose from, so I would guess it's used here $P(X^2 \leq t) =  
P( -\sqrt{t} \leq X \leq \sqrt{t})$, but I have no intuition why this is so.

Comment: $P( -\sqrt{t} \leq X \leq \sqrt{t}) =  P(X \leq \sqrt{t}) - P(X < -\sqrt{t})$ in general.

Comment: @geetha290krm I was referring to the previous transition.

Comment: No, continuity is not used in the previous step.

Comment: Continuity is used here solely to say $P(X \lt -\sqrt{t})=P(X \leq -\sqrt{t})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$F_Y(t)=P(Y \leq t) = P(X^2 \leq t) =  
P( -\sqrt{t} \leq X \leq \sqrt{t}) =  $$
$$P(X \leq \sqrt{t}) - P(X < -\sqrt{t}) = F_X(\sqrt{t}) - F_X((-\sqrt{t})-)$$ where $F(s-)$ denotes the left-hand limit of $F(s)$ at $s$. Since $X$ is continuous it follows that we can replace $F(s-)$ by $F(s)$ so we get $$F_Y(t)=F_X(\sqrt{t}) - F_X((-\sqrt{t})).$$

Comment: I didn't notice that there was a $<$ instead of a $\leq$ in your comment. Now it makes sense. Thank you.